# Need help finding memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

In my CST class we are learning about memory on the heap in C++. Keep in mind this is how the code should be written (must use no std::vector or similar helpful classes). Below is the code I wrote to my assignment and I tested it for memory leaks through Visual Studio and is returns:

```
{173} normal block at 0x008BF658, 257 bytes long.
Data: <                > 00 CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
```

which is this line : `names[i] = new char[257];`

but later on I delete it with : `delete [] names[i];`

Don't know why this isn't working. Here is my code consisting of a simple recursive function and the main:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include "CST126SRS02.h"

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <crtdbg.h>  


using namespace std;


void reverseNames(int &numNames, char ** &names, char ** &temp)
{
    //get names from user, put names in ragged array
    names = new char * [numNames] {};
    int i = 0;
    while (i < numNames) {
        //add name to ragged array
        if (cin.peek() == '\n' && i != 0) break; //make sure there are names
        if (!cin.good()) return; //end of file or errors 

        names[i] = new char[257];
        cin >> setw(256) >> names[i];
        i++;

        if (i == numNames) {
            //need a bigger array, reallocation
            numNames *= 2;

            temp = new char *[numNames] {};
            for (int j = 0; j < numNames / 2; j++)
            {
                temp[j] = names[j];
            }

            delete[] names;
            names = temp;
        }
    }

    //output names in reverse order
    for (int i = numNames - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (names[i] != nullptr) cout << names[i] << " ";
        delete [] names[i]; //also deletes temp items!
    }
    delete [] names; //also deletes temp array!
    cout << endl;

    //recursion
    numNames = 1;
    reverseNames(numNames, names, temp);
}

int main()
{
    //_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    //_CrtSetBreakAlloc(173);

    int numNames = 1;
    char **names;
    char ** temp;

    //recursive function, runs until user ends file
    reverseNames(numNames, names, temp);

    delete [] names;

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();

    return 0;
}
```

Where is the memory leak? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ideally you would use `std::vector`. If you can't because your university is bad then implement it yourself. Keep [the rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) in mind. If you are not allowed to do that either print out every pointer you allocate and every pointer you deallocate along with the line number so you can afterwards check which line allocated memory but wasn't deallocated.

Comment: "if you can't because your university is bad"  Are you serious?  So let me get this straight, you never had any examples of the reasons WHY you would use vector?

Comment: Match every `new` with a `delete`, and every `new[]` with a `delete[]`.  Too bad you cannot use `std::vector` and `std::string`.

Comment: @Michael Not when you can apparently use iostreams, which are much larger and more complex than things like vectors.

Comment: `names = new char * [numNames] {};` in main and your function. No reason to check for this: `if (name != nullptr)`

Comment: @Retired Ninja without the if statement there are errors because you can't print nullptrs. The delete in main got rid of one leak.

Comment: I never see that the memory allocated for the variable `temp` is freed.

Comment: @flashingx names is equal to temp when I delete them so they are both deleted to my understanding.

Comment: Why is there a nullptr in your array? Did you expect the while loop to run more than once?

Comment: @Jared Sorry yeah I see. I think it is because you allocate memory for the variable `names` in the main function and then in your recursive function you allocate it again without using the previously allocated memory. By removing the allocation in main it works.

Comment: @flashingx Yes! That was one of the leaks! now it's just names[i] = new char[257]; that leaks

Comment: I updated the question to show where my last memory leak is. Have know idea why this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this if happens `names` variable will leak.

```
if (!cin.good()) return; //end of file or errors
```

To be precise in this case `new char[257];` will not be deallocated on return.

Comment: Yep! Thanks, that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Memory Leak Detection
This line will output memory leak information to output window.

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
```

Take the value in the paranthesis and insert into this line below (183, 184, 150).
The application will then break at the allocation of the memory 
leak which you can trace back through the call stack.

```
_CrtSetBreakAlloc(Your value);
```

Adding info specifically for this thread:

```
char** array = new char*[size]; //This is an array of pointers.
for(int i=0; i<size;i++) { array[i] = new char(); } // Each element in the array creates an object.
```

To delete:

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){ delete array[i]; } //delete the objects.
delete[] array; //delete the array.
```

Comment: So they point to char **names = new char * [numNames] {}; and names[i] = new char[257]; Now what? I delete both of them later on I think.

Comment: You have now detected where you allocate the memory that leaks. Each new has to be freed up by a matching "delete". The other comments on the OP describes it. Basically: You allocate memory. After it is used, you have to free it up.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I don't see how "names[i] = new char[257];" is leaking. To my knowledge I delete later on with "delete [] names[i];" Why isn't this working?

Comment: Thanks but if you look at my code that is what I do. Still have the issue on the line I referenced :(

Comment: remove the [] after delete in your second to last comment.